# Import images after git clone

Tags: 8, version-control

So I did a git clone to get my Drupal 8 site working locally on another PC. This project already has a lot of nodes (articles) with images attached to them.
The site works perfect, but of course I did not push the images to git. So ATM I'm a bit confused as to where I should add these images. Is there a proper way to import these with a module or setting? I'm still learning so could be a simple thing I missed. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [stage_file_proxy](https://www.drupal.org/project/stage_file_proxy) module is what you're looking for.

You can configure this module to download images on the fly, i.e. as they're needed, or have your local environment serve them straight from your remote environment.

From the project page on d.o, the simplest install:

```
composer require drupal/stage_file_proxy
drush en stage_file_proxy
drush config-set stage_file_proxy.settings origin "https://www.example.com"
```

The module's *INSTALL.md* file goes into more detail about all of the module's options.